# Why are the two plots in a tab panel not visible?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

I need to display in one of the `tabPanel`s two plots (`sim_plot`), I have added a `tabPanel` with `fluidRow` but it does not display any plot as I want.

But when I run it, it does not display anything in the screen:

The code that I am using is:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("webapp"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("nro_patients","Enter number of patients", 1000),
      sliderInput("readmission_rate","Enter the readmission rate",
                  min = 0.01,max = 0.05,value=0.032),
      numericInput("nro_simulations","Number of Simulations",100),
      
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel( 
      
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Distribution of Costs",
                 fluidRow(12,column(6,plotOutput("sim_plot")),
                          column(12, plotOutput("sim_plot"))
                 )),
        tabPanel("Resultados",plotOutput("Plot_final"))
      )
    )
  )
)


server<- function(input,output,session){
  

  
  output$sim_plot<-renderPlot({
    sim_read<-rbinom(n=input$nro_patients,prob = input$readmission_rate,size=1)
    sims<-mapply(1:input$nro_patients,
                 FUN=function(x)
                   ifelse(sim_read[x]==1,
                          rgamma(10000,shape= 2.200213e+00,rate=6.122054e-05),
                          rgamma(10000,shape= 3.0185822348,rate=0.0001600063)))
    
    sim_read<-as.factor(sim_read)
    
    plot3<-data.frame(status=sim_read,cost=sims)|> ggplot(aes(x=cost,fill=status))+
      geom_density(alpha=0.4)+xlim(c(0,100000))
    plot3
    
  })
  
  output$Plot_final<-renderPlot({
    residuals<-NULL
    after<-NULL
    before<-NULL
    nro_simulations<-input$nro_simulations
    nro_patients<-input$nro_patients
    readmission_rate<-input$readmission_rate
    
    for (i in 1:nro_simulations){
      N1<-round(n_patients*(readmission_rate),digits = 0)
      N2<-round(n_patients*(1-readmission_rate),digits=0)
      cost1<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N1,shape= 2.200213e+00,rate=6.122054e-05),status="Readmitted")
      cost2<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N2,shape= 3.0185822348,rate=0.0001600063),status="No Readmitted")
      dataset <- rbind(cost1,cost2)
      
      
      readmission_rate1<-(1-readjustment)*readmission_rate
      N11<-round(n_patients*(readmission_rate1),digits = 0)
      N21<-round(n_patients*(1-readmission_rate1),digits=0)
      
      cost11<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N11,shape= 2.200213e+00,rate=6.122054e-05),status="Readmitted")
      cost21<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N21,shape= 3.0185822348,rate=0.0001600063),status="No Readmitted")
      dataset1 <- rbind(cost11,cost21)
      res_cost<-dataset|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()-dataset1|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()
      before[i]<-dataset|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()
      after[i]<-dataset1|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()
      residuals[i]<-res_cost
      print(i)
    }
    plot<-rbind(data.frame(tot=after,type="after"),data.frame(tot=before,type="before"))|>
      ggplot(aes(x=tot,fill=type))+geom_density(alpha=0.4)+
      labs(title="Distribution Simulated Total Cost before and after HRRP")+
      theme_classic()
    plot
  })
  

  
  
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The output of the app is the following:

[image]

What is the mistake?

Comment: `outputID`s and `inputID`s have to be unique, you are using `plotOutput("sim_plot")` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some adjustments to your code:

1. I deleted `column(12, plotOutput("sim_plot")` which appears redundant as you can't assign the same ID to two plot outputs. And if you are going to separate the plots, you have to write a second `render({})` function.
2. I corrected the typo `n_patients` (I assume it's a typo) and changed it to `nro_patients` according to the input logic you set for your UI. `nro_patients` is the only numeric input in your app.
3. There is no input like `readjustment` in your app. There is even no function with that argument, and that is why no result is displayed in your Results tab. Therefore, I changed `readjustment` to 0.5 in `readmission_rate1<-(1-0.5)*readmission_rate` to make sure it works. If it is going to be a user defined value, then be sure to create an input in your app, perhaps a slider input or a numeric input.

Here is the corrected code:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      titlePanel("webapp"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          numericInput("nro_patients","Enter number of patients", 1000),
          sliderInput("readmission_rate","Enter the readmission rate",
                      min = 0.01,max = 0.05,value=0.032),
          numericInput("nro_simulations","Number of Simulations",100),
          
        ),
        
        
        mainPanel( 
          
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Distribution of Costs",
                     fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("sim_plot"))
                            
                     )),
            tabPanel("Resultados",plotOutput("Plot_final"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
    
    server<- function(input,output,session){
      
      
      
      output$sim_plot<-renderPlot({
        sim_read<-rbinom(n=input$nro_patients,prob = input$readmission_rate,size=1)
        sims<-mapply(1:input$nro_patients,
                     FUN=function(x)
                       ifelse(sim_read[x]==1,
                              rgamma(10000,shape= 2.200213e+00,rate=6.122054e-05),
                              rgamma(10000,shape= 3.0185822348,rate=0.0001600063)))
        
        sim_read<-as.factor(sim_read)
        
        plot3<-data.frame(status=sim_read,cost=sims)|> ggplot(aes(x=cost,fill=status))+
          geom_density(alpha=0.4)+xlim(c(0,100000))
        plot3
        
      })
      
      output$Plot_final<-renderPlot({
        residuals<-NULL
        after<-NULL
        before<-NULL
        nro_simulations<-input$nro_simulations
        nro_patients<-input$nro_patients
        readmission_rate<-input$readmission_rate
        
        for (i in 1:nro_simulations){
          N1<-round(nro_patients*(readmission_rate),digits = 0)
          N2<-round(nro_patients*(1-readmission_rate),digits=0)
          cost1<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N1,shape= 2.200213e+00,rate=6.122054e-05),status="Readmitted")
          cost2<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N2,shape= 3.0185822348,rate=0.0001600063),status="No Readmitted")
          dataset <- rbind(cost1,cost2)
          
          
          readmission_rate1<-(1-0.5)*readmission_rate
          N11<-round(nro_patients*(readmission_rate1),digits = 0)
          N21<-round(nro_patients*(1-readmission_rate1),digits=0)
          
          cost11<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N11,shape= 2.200213e+00,rate=6.122054e-05),status="Readmitted")
          cost21<-data.frame(cost=rgamma(N21,shape= 3.0185822348,rate=0.0001600063),status="No Readmitted")
          dataset1 <- rbind(cost11,cost21)
          res_cost<-dataset|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()-dataset1|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()
          before[i]<-dataset|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()
          after[i]<-dataset1|>group_by(status)|> pull(cost)|> sum()
          residuals[i]<-res_cost
          print(i)
        }
        plot<-rbind(data.frame(tot=after,type="after"),data.frame(tot=before,type="before"))|>
          ggplot(aes(x=tot,fill=type))+geom_density(alpha=0.4)+
          labs(title="Distribution Simulated Total Cost before and after HRRP")+
          theme_classic()
        plot
      })
      
      
      
      
    }
    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

[image]

[image]